# Best program for anallizing VoIP connection?

Tags: voip, skype

I'm working on my master thesis, and I need to analise network (routes, nodes, protocols, quality of connection...) used in VoIP connection between two devices. I have a couple of questions:

1. Which program(s) to use to get used network nodes, quality of
   connection, used protocols? Can RPTG Network Monitor do that?
2. Which is easiest way to do that? Can I use PC-to-PC or PC-to-Phone connection (i.e. Skype
   Connect, to avoid using extra hardware for VoIP), because it is cheapest way?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski Currently Windows 8.1 x64, but I can install Linux if that is necessary, better or easier to get job done.

Answer (score 0):

To do network traffic analysis http://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: Thanks, @Simone. I will take a look on this software related to my needs presented in question.